# Comparison principle for reaction-diffusion equation: See $0\leq u(x,t)\leq 1$ and $u\to 0$ faster than $s(t)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the book *Patterns and Waves* by Peter Grindrod, the following *comparison principle is given*:

[image: Comparison principle]

Next, an example is given that I do not fully understand.

Consider the scalar equation
$$
u_t=\Delta u+u(1-u)(u-a),\qquad x\in\Omega, t>0,
$$
and $a$ is constant in $(0,1)$, $\Omega$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, together with no-flux boundary conditions
$$
\nabla u\cdot n=0,\qquad x\in\partial\Omega,t>0.
$$

> > **1.)** If $0\leq u(x,0)\leq 1$ for $x\in\Omega$, from comparison principle it follows that
> >     $$
> > 0\leq u(x,t)\leq 1~\text{whenenver solution u exists}.
> > $$
> >
> > **2.)** Suppose $0\leq u(x,0)<a$ for $x\in\Omega$, then, the comparison principle implies that $u\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ faster as $s(t)$, where
> >     $$
> > s_t=s(1-s)(s-a),\qquad s(0)=\max_{x\in\Omega}u(x,0).
> > $$

I did not understand both 1.) and 2.) yet.

For 1.), it is said we have to take $\overline{u}\equiv 1, \underline{u}\equiv u$ etc.

For 2.), it is said we have to take $\overline{u}\equiv s,~~\underline{u}\equiv u$.

**ad 1.)** What I see is that $\overline{u}\equiv 1$ is a super-solution and supposed that $u$ is a solution, it of course satisfies the inequality in order to be a sub-solution. Moreover, it is assumed that $u(x,0)\leq 1$ on $\Omega$, so
$$
\overline{u}(x,0)\geq\underline{u}(x,0),~~x\in\Omega~~~~(1)
$$
is clear.

But for me it is not clear that
$$
\alpha\overline{u}-\beta\nabla\overline{u}\cdot n\geq\alpha\underline{u}-\beta\nabla\underline{u}\cdot n,~~x\in\partial\Omega, t>0~~~(2)
$$
for $\overline{u}\equiv 1,~\underline{u}\equiv u$ and some constant $\alpha,\beta$. My idea would be that we can just choose $\alpha=0$ and *any* $\beta\neq 0$ since the products of gradients and normal vectors are 0 on both sides (by assumption on the RHS and since 1 is a constant function on the LHS).

I guess one then next chooses $\underline{u}\equiv 0, \overline{u}\equiv u$ and can show the same analogously in order to get the final result.

**ad 2.)** I do not see that $s$ is a super-solution and that (1) and (2) are satisfied with $\overline{u}=s,~\underline{u}=u$. Moreover, I do not understand how the claim follows from the comparison principle.

Comment: you may want to use \cdot instead of . if it should be scalar product.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1. I think your idea $\alpha = 0$ / $\beta = 1$ is legit.

Ad 2. The spatially constant function $s$ indeed satisfies $\partial_t s = \Delta s + f(s)$, where $f(u) = u \, (1 - u) \, (u - a)$, and $\nabla \cdot s = 0$ on the boundary. It is, in particular, a supersolution. By assumption $s(0) := \max_x u(x, t=0)$ satisfies $s(x,0) \geq u(x, t=0)$ for all $x$, and the gradient condition is as in the first point. The comparison principle gives $s(t) \geq u(x,t)$ for all $t$. There is maybe a minor point of convincing yourself that $s(0) < a$. But from that, the ODE for $s$ implies that $s(t) \searrow 0$ as $t \to \infty$, and therefore $\max_x u(x,t) \searrow 0$ at least as fast.